# Can't convert this snippet to Objective C - ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a convenient class when I want to call an alert in a button like this:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    [MyAlertView showWithTitle:@"test" withCallBackBlock:^(int value){
        NSLog(@"Button Pressed %i", value); 
    }];
}
```

The class is very simple:

```
    @implementation MyAlertView
@synthesize callBackBlock = _callBackBlock, internalCallBackBlock = _internalCallBackBlock;

-(void)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title withCallBackBlock:(CallBackBlock )callBackBlock internalCallBackBlock:(CallBackBlock )internalCallBackBlock{
    self.callBackBlock = callBackBlock;
    self.internalCallBackBlock = internalCallBackBlock;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK" , nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView autorelease];
    });

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (_callBackBlock) {
        _callBackBlock(buttonIndex);
    }

    if (_internalCallBackBlock) {
        _internalCallBackBlock(buttonIndex);
    }
}


-(void)dealloc{
    Block_release(_callBackBlock);
    Block_release(_internalCallBackBlock);
    [super dealloc];
}


+(void)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title withCallBackBlock:(CallBackBlock )callBackBlock{
    __block MyAlertView *alert = [[MyAlertView alloc]init];
    [alert showWithTitle:title withCallBackBlock:callBackBlock internalCallBackBlock:^(int value){
        [alert autorelease];
    }];

}
@end
```

I've profiled it on the simulator and it shows no leaks, no zombies.
Now, when I change to ARC,
The program crashes every time I click the test button, even though I reference everything as strong. I'm guessing thats because I'm not holding to the alertView variable.

How can one do a convenience class like this with ARC ?

Appending the .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void(^CallBackBlock)(int value);

@interface MyAlertView : NSObject<UIAlertViewDelegate>


@property (copy) CallBackBlock callBackBlock, internalCallBackBlock;

+(void)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title withCallBackBlock:(CallBackBlock )callBackBlock;
@end
```

Comment: Is your alert view still autoreleased?

Comment: When I converted the project to arc, it removed all autorelease calls and the dealloc method too. So I don't know how to check that

Comment: wasn't sure if you used the built in Xcode converter

Answer (score 0):

You're right: the problem is that the `UIAlertView` created in 
`showWithTitle:withCallBackBlock:internalCallBackBlock:internalCallBackBlock` is not being retained.

The trick is to store is at an instance variable of `MyAlertView`. So in `MyAlertView.m`, add the following:

```
@interface MyAlertView()
    @property(strong) UIAlertView *alertView;
@end

@implementation MyAlertView

@synthesize alertView;

...
```

And use it to store the `UIAlertView` you create in `showWithTitle:withCallBackBlock:internalCallBackBlock:internalCallBackBlock`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK" , nil];
    [self.alertView show];
});
```

P.S. This is going to be really pedantic, but `MyAlertView` isn't actually a view so you might want to rename it.

Comment: It still crashes. I think its because on the class method I'm not holding "MyAlertview" instance variable. Although I set it to __strong, I think the compiler is releasing it before the async call maybe ?

Comment: Ok, Ive checked with the profiler, its definitely the "MyAlerView" instance. The responsible caller "UIAlertView(private) _buttonClicked:"] tries to call its dealloc(ed) delegate